# Simplest way to parameterize/configure php application | human friendly data serialization

Tags: php, text, customization

When development time matters, all that others can help is a goal.  My PHP app is now parameterized & configured with an include file that contains an array in the form:

```
$config = array(
   'company'            => 'BMC' ,       // the visible company name
   'aplicable_tax'      => .21   ,       // the IVA tax
   'context_arr'        => array(
        'case1'             =>    12,    // the defalul value
        'case2'             =>    13,
        'case3'             =>    14
                           ),
   'EN_welcome_text'       => 'hello',   // do NOT translate on regionalization

   // xx comparation matrix
   'xx_maxref'=> 5,
   'xx_range' => array( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
   'xx_comp'  => array( 
    //  V Other V  > I >>   0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
        /*  0 */     array( 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
        /*  1 */     array(-3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
        /*  2 */     array(-5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
        /*  3 */     array(-5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
        /*  4 */     array(-5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5),
        /*  5 */     array(-5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5),
        /*  6 */     array(-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5),
        /*  7 */     array(-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5),
        /*  8 */     array(-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3),
        /*  9 */     array(-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0),
),


// and so on
// and so on
// and so on
)
```

But this approach is insecure, because any allowed editor can inject PHP code or errors.

My Questions:

- Can you suggest a simple and flexible format to give three party a way to parameterize a PHP app?
- Is there a conversion script from that format into a PHP?

Comment: Simple truth is - if you can access the code, you can break the code.

Comment: `parse_ini_file()` do not manage 2D arrays  `json` do not manage comments  `XML` is too much verbose for a human editor: any single value needs tags.  I will write the parser, if it is necesary (I have writen some yet), so please suggest an usefull "data" format. (and if you want the `regexes`, or related stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great alternative to XML is YAML. YAML's syntax is light and easy to read/write for anybody. Another great point is that YAML makes a difference between hashes and arrays. I recommend you the symfony stand-alone component : http://fabien.potencier.org/article/40/the-state-of-yaml-in-php

your file would look like :

```
company: BMC         #the visible company name
aplicable_tax: 0.21  #the IVA tax
context_arr:
    case1: 12       #the defalul value
    case2: 13
    case3: 14
EN_welcome_text: hello #do NOT translate on regionalization

#xx comparation matrix
xx_maxref: 5
xx_range: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
xx_comp:
# V Other V  > I >>   0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    -[  0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ] # [ 0 ]
    -[ -3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ] # [ 1 ]
    -[ -5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ] # [ 2 ]
    -[ -5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ] # [ 3 ]
    -[ -5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5 ] # [ 4 ]
    -[ -5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5 ] # [ 5 ]
    -[ -5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5, 5 ] # [ 6 ]
    -[ -5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3, 5 ] # [ 7 ]
    -[ -5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0, 3 ] # [ 8 ]
    -[ -5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3, 0 ] # [ 9 ]
```

YAML has all XML advantage and even more.

Comment: wonderful, quoted from your link: **human friendly data serialization**  I will add to the title. thanks

Comment: @Luis: I was going to write my own answer, but I don't see why anymore - YAML is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Your spec regarding *security from a third-party breaking the code* can not be achieved if the third-party has access to the code.

The solutions provided so far all have limitations that in my opinion break more imporatant items of your spec - *flexibility* and *maintainability*.

- **Database Solution** may separate the
  configuration options from the code,
  but you lose flexibility of format
  (e.g. comments, complex data types)
  and increase complexity losing maintainability. Furthermore, if a developer has access to the code, they could simply overwrite the configurations options.
- **Encoding Solution** - this includes JSON, Serialization, and INI - same problems the Database Solution. Limited to the format of the encoding. Added a layer of complexity. Developer with project access can still overwrite the configuration options.
- **Database + Encoding Solution** contains all the same problems.

I reiterate - *if you can access the code, you can break the code*. A PHP config file is a very common way to configure your project. If you don't trust developers with it, don't give them access. Don't obfuscate the code and sacrifice maintainability.

#### UPDATE REGARDING PHP CONFIG FILE

If you are requesting an answer for *the **simplest** way to **configure** a **PHP** application*, the that would be an INI file. PHP's core configuration comes from such files. It's format offers all the syntax you require - comments, arrays, etc. It can be parsed with a native function - [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php). If you are concerned about security/access, as noted above, you can exclude it from the project or keep it in a separate location. Conversely, if you want to allow someone to configure the app without access to the code, they could simply edit the INI file.

#### UPDATE REGARDING nD Arrays

While it is true `parse_ini_file()` does not support multidimensional arrays, you can combine sections with arrays to provide more complex configuration. Anything beyond that, in my opinion, is dangerously close to flat data file - not a configuration file - and belongs elsewhere (i.e. database).

Comment: I agree all you say, but what is the solution?  what do you mean with _"a PHP config file is a very common way to configure your project"_?  I trusts developers, I am the only one ... jaja. But I ask for my minimun efort (and third-party involved), without loosing clarity and flexibility. in example I need to have it solved to have a way to translate the app (all error messages are there). Also the app will be tuned (ponderating values) in this way. Thank you very much. Excuse my english.

Comment: I have updated my answer with my proposed solution for a **PHP** application.

Comment: I have updated my answer with comments regarding multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I find the easiest and most flexible format to be [JSON](http://json.org/) using PHPs built in [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Your configuration array then looks like this:

```
{
    "company" : "BMC",
    "aplicable_tax" : 0.21,
    "context_arr" :
    {
        "case1" : 12,
        "case2" : 13,
        "case3" : 14
    },
    "EN_welcome_text" : "hello"
}
```

The advantage is, that you can also store the configuration somewhere else (e.g. a database) and don't have to give users direct access to the filesystem.

Comment: The `serialize()` is not much suitable to store variable in db?

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't use serialize for stuff that can be edited by a user. And yes, no comments, you have to create an actual documentation for the configuration object structure - e.g. json schema http://json-schema.org/.

Comment: I really like to use JSON for such things too, it's clean and easy. The only downside is that in case there's something wrong with the JSON syntax (missing comma, quotes, etc.), the `json_decode()` function won't give you a hint where the problem is. (Using PHP files is even worse, since users usually don't understand PHP errors and you can't catch syntax errors.)

Answer (score 1):

I use a DB table which has a key, a value and a description.
I request the config value by its key and the description is displayed on the configure page.

One way to protect your config file is to ask for a previusly defined constant, which you'll define in your scripts.

Comment: You can serialize()... But haven't needed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Put this data into XML structure - guaranteed without code execution, multi-nested levels, any type of data structure, comments. All what you need, and IDE syntax highlight as advantage.
For parsing - [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) (as variant).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use .ini files for configuration. Not only they're pretty much a standard, and very human-readable, it will make configuring your application easier. This function can help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

But, you should remember what Jason said: "Simple truth is - if you can access the code, you can break the code"

Answer (score 0):

Given that .ini and .xml have been rejected, I'd consider this:

- Remove the $config = array( line and ); lines, keeping just the key => value mappings & comments
- Instead of including the config file, do something similar to:

  eval("$config = array("+file_get_contents('config.file')+");");

You should parse `config.file` a bit, to provide more protection against injection - off the top of my head, an unquoted / uncommented `;` is the dangerous character, there may be others. Most errors should just cause the eval to fail.

That said, if you don't trust the 3rd party not to supply a dangerous include file, then you need to pick a different approach. Can you provide the 3rd-party with a web interface that posts config files to you? The comments/hints would be on-screen in HTML, but you'd have nice, safe JSON to parse.

Comment: It is still possible to inject PHP code in config.file. Think SQL-Injection.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "You should parse"... I was illustrating a method, not writing a full solution for the OP

Comment: Don't worry, we all do it from time to time :)